# Play back Rational Functional Tester

Tags: java, rft

How to play back Rational Functional Tester 8.1 without IDE instead use command prompt please provide the command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IBM RFT command line execution -datastore -playback parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468060/ibm-rft-command-line-execution-datastore-playback-parameter)

Answer (score 4):

Do a search for "command line" at the following link:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rfthelp/v8r1/index.jsp

You'll get a full page of info.

Answer (score 1):

java -classpath "Path for rational_ft.jar" com.rational.ft.test.rational_ft -datastore "projectfilePath" -compile "scriptName"

java -classpath "Path for rational_ft.jar" com.rational.ft.test.rational_ft -datastore "projectfilePath" -playback "scriptName"

Answer (score 0):

java -classpath "%IBM_RATIONAL_RFT_INSTALL_DIR%\rational_ft.jar" com.rational.test.ft.rational_ft -datastore C:\Users\username\IBM\rationalsdp\workspace\Project1  -playback Script1 -log Script1