# IBM RFT command line execution -datastore -playback parameter

Tags: command-line, datastore, rft

I need to start my RFT scripts with a .bat script. I tried this with:

```
"%IBM_RATIONAL_RFT_INSTALL_DIR%\rational_ft.exe" -datastore "C:\project" -playback "test"
```

In the .bat file. With a test project in `C:\project` and a test script named test.java.

When I start the batch file, RFT opens a playback window and is looking for the script. But I always receive a error:

> [Rational.Test.Ft.Application.ScriptPlaybackException: Could not get type for [test].

I found out that this must be a problem with the path of the test script.

But I still don't know what is going on, the path is correct and I tried everything without a positive result. RFT playback starts, but still cant find this script.

I hope anybody can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the command you tried to start RFT I get the same error. I don't know what the `rational_ft.exe` is for, but it works when you don't call this but the `java.exe` with the class `com.rational.test.ft.rational_ft`:

```
"%IBM_RATIONAL_RFT_ECLIPSE_DIR%\jdk\jre\bin\java" -classpath "%IBM_RATIONAL_RFT_INSTALL_DIR%\rational_ft.jar" com.rational.test.ft.rational_ft -datastore C:\project -playback Test
```

See [this IBM developerWorks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/run-scripts-through-the-rational-functional-tester-command-line/) for more information.